# Where is the Haskell course mentioned by Lars?

Tags: haskell

In the welcome video, Lars mentions about a 10-week Haskell course recording. Where can I get the link for that course? It would be good for other beginners as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lars's courses are spread around various Youtube channels. I think that the one you are referring to is "Crypto Mongolia". Here it is:

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJ3w5xyG4JWmBVIigNBytJhvSSfZZzfTm

And here is another course on Haskell that I found useful:

https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLe7Ei6viL6jGp1Rfu0dil1JH1SHk9bgDV